# magento php-fpm too many process

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, magento

in the last 2 days, suddenly the server is very slow.
we are running magento, and we have seen 40-50 php-fpm process being run, each taking a few % of cpu, making performance very slow.
we have 2 servers, each 4 GB ram, for web and db.

using apc already, with 100% hit rate.
php memory limit 256M

php-fpm using max_children = 100, and max_requests = 1,000

can anyone please help explain why suddenly magento have 40-50 php process running?
(basically once we restart nginx and php-fpm, the no. of php-fpm process just jumps to 40-50)

please help. thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually there is not enough information in this post to make any conclusions. As a guess I would suggest that your database got too big and having trouble processing all the queries thus page load time has increased which in turn increased the number of processes.
Another guess would be that you ran a marketing campaign, or that you are being DOSed or any combination of the above.

Comment: Not really. Website traffic is same as last week. And DB server (separate server) is all ok, fast and stable